# what is the best way to create primitive wrapper class in Java

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive-types

I know in Java, there are three different ways below to transform the primitive types to their corresponding wrapper classes. However, is there any preferred way if performance is critical ?

```
Integer i = new Integer(5);
Integer i = 5;
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is better in terms of performance, implicit (auto) unboxing or explicit unboxing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915823/which-is-better-in-terms-of-performance-implicit-auto-unboxing-or-explicit-un)

Comment: "if performance is critical" it may depend on task you are running. `Integer i = 5;` thanks to autoboxing is same as `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);` which thanks to internal caching of integers in range `-128,127` will let you reuse these instances of `Integer` class so you will use less space. But if you don't care about space then `new Integer(5)` may be faster because you will skip searching for cached ints.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Integer vs valueOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561/new-integer-vs-valueof)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javadocs for [Integer.valueOf(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) emit a pretty clear recommendation:

> If a new `Integer` instance is not required, ***this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Integer(int)`, as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance*** by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range `-128` to `127`, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

And as pointed out by `Pshemo` in the comments, and as considered in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408661/what-code-does-the-compiler-generate-for-autoboxing), `Integer i = 5;` essentially gets converted automatically to `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);`.  So using either won't make a difference performance-wise.

So if performance is a concern, simply avoid using `new Integer(5)` to benefit from the caching.